# How to properly customize Angular material v15 range slider?

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to create custom Angular material v15 range slider (updates made in component level scss )
What I want to do is:

- Create custom colors
- Change track, handle size and shape ( like i want to make track thicker and handler rectangle instead of round )

The problem is I can not seems to find what elements/classes i need to edit to achieve what I want

for example the docs sample I'm working on:

```html
      <mat-slider min="200" max="500" color="primary">
        <input value="300" matSliderStartThumb />
        <input value="400" matSliderEndThumb />
      </mat-slider>
```

after hours of research and trail and error:
I tried editing `mat-slider` but it only affect container level
I tried to edit `input` i get no changes at all

the only thing that worked was editing colors using bellow approach that i find not practical and clunky

```scss
.mat-mdc-slider.mat-primary {
  --mdc-slider-handle-color: #c2185b;
  --mdc-slider-focus-handle-color: #c2185b;
  --mdc-slider-hover-handle-color: #c2185b;
  --mdc-slider-active-track-color: #c2185b;
  --mdc-slider-inactive-track-color: #c2185b;
  --mdc-slider-with-tick-marks-active-container-color: #fff;
  --mdc-slider-with-tick-marks-inactive-container-color: #c2185b;
  --mat-mdc-slider-ripple-color: #c2185b;
  --mat-mdc-slider-hover-ripple-color: rgba(194, 24, 91, 0.05);
  --mat-mdc-slider-focus-ripple-color: rgba(194, 24, 91, 0.2);
}
```

other than that no thing worked